# Grid positing issues

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm new to CSS/grid layouts in general, i'm having trouble getting the three columns I created to show up under the full width grid (16 cols). The only way around this is to set a min-height...

Here's the layout:

http://projects.upbeatdev.com/cats/ (if you view source or remove position absolute from .text-overlay and .image the three column grid will show up like it's suppose to)

It should look like this

> HEADER
>    16 COLS
>    1/3 col 1/3 col 1/3 col

Code below, see at the bottom.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <section id="header" class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="six columns">
                     <h1>ONE GOOD DEED TODAY.</h1>

                </div>
                <div class="seven columns">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">ITEM</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">ITEM</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">ITEM</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="last"><a href="#">ITEM</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form id="search">
                        <input type="input" name="search" value="search" />
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="three columns">
                    <div class="eight columns">
                        <div class="row">hello</div>
                        <div class="row">hello</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="eight columns">
                        <div class="row">hello</div>
                        <div class="row">hello</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="homepage" class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="sixteen columns alpha omega">
                    <div class="text-overlay">
                         <h1>TITLE</h1>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce tincidunt hendrerit enim at tristique. Aliquam purus sapien, eleifend imperdiet feugiat eu, consequat nec nisi. Phasellus condimentum urna a lacus consequat vestibulum. Curabitur vulputate nulla ac lacus pharetra iaculis. Nam et lectus nibh, sed pellentesque augue. Nulla ultricies vulputate mi eu tristique. Sed tellus leo, aliquam et iaculis a, tincidunt a neque. Sed congue sapien a erat dictum eget volutpat ligula interdum. Sed turpis dolor, tincidunt a tempus vitae, commodo et turpis. Nunc ultrices libero fringilla libero varius nec convallis ipsum convallis. Sed aliquam euismod felis, sit amet lobortis sem viverra non.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="image">
                        <img class="scale-with-grid" src="img/homepage-1.png" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="one-third column alpha omega">a</div>
                <div class="one-third column alpha omega">a</div>
                <div class="one-third column alpha omega">a</div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
section#header h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#000;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
section#header ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 33px;
}
section#header ul li a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.last {
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
section#homepage .text-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
section#homepage .image {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: you should maybe take a look at the [html5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider creating wrapper divs.

The problem here is that your elements are conflicting because of the float left

```
.container .columns {
      float: left;
     }
```

If you place wrappers around the block sections that you want in the grid you can apply float:left to the elements inside the wrapper with the wrapper div still maintaining the structure. So the wrapper divs for each section are

```
#wrapper{
   display:block;
   width:100%;
   // plus any other code that you need
   // If you use .less you can very neatly add the other elements like so
   .seven columns{
     //style here
   }
}
```

Comment: whoah, not sure what's going on with your CSS formatting gerdi, but that doesn't seem right. you don't define a class within an ID in CSS, maybe you meant to write that block of code as HTML instead?

Comment: i'm confused, can you give me a quick example w/ html markup?

Comment: @Joey You can do that using the .less javascript framework [less](http://lesscss.org/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard implementation of a structure using wrappers

```
<header>

  <div class="content-wrapper"> //Wrapper

      <div class="float-left"> // Here i can apply float that only effect elements inside to wrapper
         <p class="site-title"><a href="/">SITE NAME</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="float-right">
         <section id="login">
           <ul>
              <li><a href="/Account/Register" id="registerLink">Register</a></li>
              <li><a href="/Account/Login" id="loginLink">Log in</a></li>
           </ul>
         </section>

                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

        </div> //End of float right

    </div> // End of wrapper

  </header>


<div id="body">

  <section class="featured">
    <div class="content-wrapper"> // Start of new wrapper 
        <hgroup class="title">
        </hgroup>

    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">

  </section>

</div>

    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper"> //Start of last wrapper
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>Footer content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Think of the wrapper as a block that holds all the other content inside of the wrapper in that section. It holds it together to add structure .. like a box. All the other elements are inside of the "box".

the css will be something like this

```
.content-wrapper {
   margin: 0 auto;
   max-width: 960px;
   // Sometimes
   width:100%; // Depending on how you are structuring it
 }
```